# How to get hover-information with selenium / beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i would like to get the data form this hover-information on this site:
https://www.pferdewetten.de/race/17350803

When i hover eg. over the first starter "Jumby Bay" i get this hover-information:
[image]

When i inspect the code i can´t see any informations of that?
Is there any way to get this information scraped using selenium / beautiful soup?

Comment: right click inspect, go to the network tab, filter by fetch/xhr and then reload the page.

Comment: Check this out https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-can-i-perform-mouse-hover-action-in-selenium-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need hover over the name using ActionsChain and then you can extract the text off of from the tooltip.

**Code:**

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://www.pferdewetten.de/race/17350803")

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[starts-with(@class,'ParticipantInfoItem_info_horseName')]")))).perform()
print(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class,'ParticipantInfoItem_infoContainer--')]//div[starts-with(@class,'Tooltip')]"))).get_attribute('innerText'))
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**Output:**

```
Jumby Bay (2019)
Herkunft:
Frankreich
Vater:
Uriel Speed
Mutter:
Norvege
Besitzer:
Ecurie A.B Racing

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**PS:** In order to hover over each and every name, you should first take them into a list and then in a loop you should ideally perform hovering and and extracting the text in same way.

**Update:**

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://www.pferdewetten.de/race/17350803")

names = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li[starts-with(@class,'ListDivider_item--')]")))
print(len(names))
i = 1
for name in names:
    try:
        #wait.until(EC.visibility_of(name))
        time.sleep(2)
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(//span[starts-with(@class,'ParticipantInfoItem_info_horseName')])[{i}]")))).pause(2).perform()
        print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class,'ParticipantInfoItem_infoContainer--')]//div[starts-with(@class,'Tooltip')]"))).get_attribute('innerText'))
        i = i + 1
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks - seems to be a great soluton -
But how do you get the second xPath? (the first xpath is clear for me but how should i get the second one - this is not in the inspector i think)?

Comment: And also its not clear for me how i should iterate over every single racer / horse?

Comment: `Thanks - seems to be a great soluton ` - Thank you. `how do you get the second xPath?` - for this when you hover over to the names, keep a close eye on the HTML, you'd see that one div is getting appeared in HTML when we are hovering over to the names. That's how I get the second xpath.

Comment: `And also its not clear for me how i should iterate over every single racer / horse?` -  see above, this may be helpful to you.

Comment: ok thanks again - i tried your above code and it outputs the first horse - but then program stopps

Answer (score 2):

As @Sayse stated that the desired data is also dynamically loaded from api calls json response  as GET method and you also can grab data easily using only `requests` module and You have to add authentication key as header that's sent to api response in Request Headers.

```
import requests
headers={"Authorization2": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvd3d3LnBmZXJkZXdldHRlbi5kZVwvIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL3d3dy5wZmVyZGV3ZXR0ZW4uZGVcLyIsImlhdCI6MTY1MDEyODM5OCwiZXhwIjoxNjUwMTMwMTk4LCJpcCI6IjM3LjExMS4yMDUuMTQ0IiwiY28iOiJQRlciLCJjdHkiOiJCRCIsImxuZyI6Imdlcm1hbiIsImNhblJlZ2lzdGVyIjp0cnVlfQ.NQr1B6rVx5T39Zm_78959KX0bNufzWGNDQ7_Bq_dMFI"}
api_url = "https://www.pferdewetten.de/data/racecard/get/17350803"
jsonData=requests.get(api_url,headers=headers).json()

for horse in jsonData['data']['participants']:
    horse_name=horse['horse_name']
    print(horse_name)
```

**Output:**

```
Jumby Bay
Juliana Filo
Jade De Bertrange
Jaya Du Bessy
Jenny Gold
Jeny de Gouye
Jabelone
Jenesys Vallee
Jarny De Bertrange
Jordana Du Fer
Jazzy Du Liamone
Jismie Griff
Jelfa
Just Beautiful
```